# Manage node-postgres query

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, connection-pooling

I've read through node-postgres’s API documentation.

It recommended that we use the `pg` object to create pooled clients. And in `pg.connect` api documentation said:

> The connect method retrieves a Client from the client pool, or if all
>   pooled clients are busy and the pool is not full, the connect method
>   will create a new client passing its first argument directly to the
>   Client constructor.

So according to the recommendation, does using `pg.connect` mean "using the `pg` object to create pooled clients"? If it's not, what does it actually mean?

And in my implementation example, I made several queries in my route:

```
app.get('/post', function(req, res) {
  pg.connect(dbconfig, function(err, client, done) {
    client.query('SELECT * FROM post', function(err, result) {
      res.render('post/list', { posts: result.rows });
    });
  });
});

app.get('/post/new', function(req, res) {
  res.render('post/new');
});

app.post('/api/v1/post', function(req, res) {
  var b = req.body;
  pg.connect(dbconfig, function(err, client, done) {
    client.query('INSERT INTO post (title, content) VALUES ($1, $2)', 
      [b.title, b.content], 
      function(err, result) {
        done();
        res.redirect('/post');
    });
  });
});
```

Is it the right way to call `pg.connect` each time I want to make query? If not, what is the better idea?

Answer (score 0):

It does look, according to the documentation that pg.connect() does handle pooled connections.  I would suggest however one thing you could likely do better (assuming you only have one set of credentials your app is using).

If I were looking at doing this, I would work on saving duplication of effort/keystrokes/opportunities for error a bit and look at wrapping pg.connect() in some sort of function you could use that would return client.  This would enable you to do something more like:

```
app.get('/post', function(req, res) {
  db.run( function(client) {
    client.query('SELECT * FROM post', function(err, result) {
      res.render('post/list', { posts: result.rows });
    });
  });
});
```

However, given the way you have things done, I am not convinced you have a lot to gain by such an approach, so I don't see anything wrong with your approach.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a little outdated now, but take a look at this:
https://github.com/aichholzer/Bodega

It will take care of any worries and make your coding experience a little more pleasant.
:)